# Grunt shell task not getting full stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, modulus.io

I'm trying to create a Grunt task to run a [Modulus](https://modulus.io) deployment. I've installed the [Modulus npm module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/modulus) locally, as well as the [grunt-shell](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-shell) module to run the task. This is the relevant part of my Gruntfile:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  shell: {
    deploy: {
      command: 'modulus deploy',
      options: {
        cwd: 'node_modules/.bin/'
      }
    }
  }
});

grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['shell:deploy']);
```

Now, if I run the modulus command directly on the command line, I get this:

```
$ modulus deploy
Welcome to Modulus
[Error] Need to be logged in to execute this command.
Please log in with "modulus login" command.
```

When I run the grunt task though, this is what I get:

```
$ grunt deploy
Running "shell:deploy" (shell) task
Welcome to Modulus

Done, without errors.
```

The output from the Grunt command file significantly shorter than running the same command itself outside of Grunt, and is missing some key information. What could be the cause of this? Could the execution return before it has fully ended, and thus giving me an incomplete stdout?

Comment: Is it possible modulus is writing to `stderr` instead?

Comment: @jibsales that also occured to me, but [tracing](https://github.com/onmodulus/modulus-cli/blob/master/lib/modulus.js#L87) [back](https://github.com/onmodulus/modulus-cli/blob/master/lib/common/io.js#L48) [through](https://github.com/onmodulus/modulus-cli/blob/master/lib/common/io.js#L32) the Modulus code it seems to be a simple `console.log`.

Comment: @jibsales That and the fact that grunt-shell [by default also outputs `stderr`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell#stderr)